# Qt qrc dynamic rooting for static images

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator

Please, don't laugh. I've a task from my teamlead, to refactor the qml. Here is the problem. We have a Qt app with `QML` ui. We have a lot of icons, which are imported from some dir. Lets name it *images*. I know that we have a possibility of moving this directory somewhere else, via structure refactoring. So, every icon path will be corrupted in `qrc` file.

Do you have any idea how to write paths to icons in `qrc` or in `qml`, to achieve icons roots independence via moving *images* folder?

I thought that it will be a good practice to use file names' synonyms in `qrc` file, but they'll become useless after moving the *images* folder.

Comment: Can you illustrate the problem? So a representation of the `images` folder and/or a representation of `qrc`?

Comment: Give an alias for each icon in `qrc` file, and change all image, icon etc. definitions to this aliases(`source: qrc:/BUTTON`) and move the image folder wherever you want(remember, `qrc` file should be in the root directory of your resources).

Comment: @dynerp i think it won't work. Bc if i move the folder with images somewhere, i need to readd images paths to qrc file. In that case all aliases will be removed from new records in qrc, even this records have the same destination_file name.

Comment: @MIku yes, it will work. Imagine that you have a folder as `images` and you keeping your `images.qrc` file and the images in it. If you give them aliases and use in the code as I showed above, changing the directory of images will not affect anything except one line of code in CMake where you have given the `images.qrc` to the build generator. In case of you still thinking it will not work, then obviously, the question has lack of information and not pointing out the real problem

Comment: @dynerp sorry about next question, but, do u mean .pro file or where can i find and correct this Make file?

Comment: @Mike I thought that you're using CMake build generator, but it is okay. If you follow above comment the only thing you need to change will be just modify the  `qrc` path in `.pro` file as soon as `images` folder moved